# Excel macro to increase years by 1

Tags: vba, excel

I have a cell, say A1 which has a date formatted day/month/year, I want to be able to create a macro which, when pressed, adds 1 year only to the date. I've googled around and have found the function `DATE` but I am having troubles using this in a loop to add one to the year.

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = DateSerial(Year(ActiveSheet.Range("A1") )+1,Month(ActiveSheet.Range("A1")) ,Day(ActiveSheet.Range("A1")))`

Comment: Alternatively: `ActiveSheet.Range("a1") = DateAdd("yyyy",1,ActiveSheet.Range("a1"))`

Comment: thanks, could I ask why you must have ' "yyyy" ' there?

Comment: I know you asked for a macro solution, however, I'm personally loathe to use vba/macros unless absolutely necessary :) If you have the option to avoid it, you could use something like:  `=DATE(YEAR(A1)+1,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1))`  ;)

Comment: The `"yyyy"` denotes that you are adding years and not month or day.

Answer (score 0):

Three Solutions
Credit @ @Scott Craner

```
Sub test1()
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = DateSerial(Year(ActiveSheet.Range("A1") )+1,Month(ActiveSheet.Range("A1")) ,Day(ActiveSheet.Range("A1")))
End Sub
```

Credit @Kyle

```
Sub test2()
    ActiveSheet.Range("a1") = DateAdd("yyyy",1,ActiveSheet.Range("a1"))
End Sub
```

Credit @Ditto

Put Formula in `A2`

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1)+1,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1))
```